# Get parameter from url in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

My url is: localhost/school/DPC
In the above url **school** is my controller class and **DPC** is the school name. I want to get the name **DPC** from the url in the **school** controller class.

In routes.php page I have used

```
$route['default_controller'] = "school";
```

Now what do I have to do such that I can get the school name from the url.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a profile page like other website are using ... `abc.com/hameed`
 **right**?
If yes then in Route you should also add this

```
$route['school/(:any)'] = "school/profile/$1";
```

And in your **school** controller you can do this

```
function profile($school_name){
  echo $school_name ; 
}
```

Comment: Here actually the url will be abc.com/school/JDS the what will be the $route. I have tried your example but still it shows 404 error page not found

Comment: yah but you write the answer for the url abc.com/school but it actually be abc.com/school/JDS and also my default controller set in router is $route['default_controller'] = "school";

Comment: ok tell me one thing can you place above line of code in your routes file's ?

Comment: yah i have placed it in router.php file in the config folder

Comment: Ok Cool. Now do you have function name profile in your school controller ?

Comment: here I am used schoolname function in the school controller and in router page I have just used $route['school/(:any)'] = "school/schoolname/$1";

Comment: yap its right now ... Just call the function like 
abc.com/school/JDS
It must b echoed the school name

Comment: public function index()
  {
   $this->schoolname($schoolName);
  }
  public function schoolname($schoolName)
  {
   echo $schoolName;
   $this->load->view('school_view',$this->data);
  } Here I am used this code

Comment: For index page controlling I am use .htaccess rule For that it is independent of index page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17128/discussion-between-hameed-and-banshi)

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, " localhost/school/DPC " , it will be intepreted by codeigniter in the following way:

'school' as controller and 'DPC' as a function name of 'school' controller class.

Since you are expecting to send DPC directly through url, you should make one function inside school class say 'myFunction' with a parameter say '$name' then your url will look like "localhost/school/myFunction/DPC" then only you can get your desired result.

Remember: the url format of CI is "hostname/controller/function/parameter". You are missing the function name that accepts that parameter.

Comment: Do you know about routes or htaccess ?

Comment: Whatever you do, you have to explicitly provide the function name before you pass the parameter. Providing parameter without function name cannot be routed. I have tested it too. Even index function of the controller should be explicitly mentioned if you are thinking of doing your task in index function of ur controller like this "hostname/controller/index/parameter"

Comment: Ooh man i think you first study about route or htaccess.. with url routing you can do this..
Ok let me tell one thing i want to create a url like example.com/username ... what should i do.. Can i make multiple controllers.... ???? Offcource no... Firstly you have to read about routes